# Manage DNS Server from Gnome

Tags: linux, dns, centos, bind, gnome

Is there a UI component for Gnome (or perhaps web-based) that allows you to setup and manage a DNS server (Bind or otherwise)? I've worked with web-based DNS services and Windows DNS but have never worked with Bind or another Linux DNS Server directly. I'm hoping there's a UI that can ease me into creating a simple DNS setup for my tiny local network. My server is running CentOS 6.2.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [webmin](http://webmin.com/) and [virtualmin](http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html). They were easy to use. If all you want to manage is Bind, they are probably overkill.